# How do I set up a wiki table formatting class in a CSS sheet?

Tags: css, wiki

I'm trying to set up a formatting class for tables on a wiki I'm building, and I've hit a wall on my very rudimentary CSS knowledge. Following online tutorials, I tried to create a .navbox class in the CSS sheet and alter settings for table, th, and td, but I hit an error message.

This is about as far as I got:

```css
.navbox {
    border: 2px solid black;
    th {
        background-color: gray;
    }
}
```

Fandom's built-in compiler gave an error message on the "th" line saying "expected COLON at line 3, col 8", and another on the last line saying "unexpected token '}' at line 6, col 1".

I want to make this table: https://aeon14.fandom.com/wiki/Template:New_Canaan_system

...look something like this: https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Template:Ships_named_Enterprise

Comment: That's [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/guide) syntax. The compiler you are using supports that? If not, you should remove the `th` from the `.navbox`: `.navbox th { background-color: gray; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your using some SCSS syntax instead of CSS

Try this :

```
.navbox {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.navbox th {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see the problem. I have to edit individual HTML commands in separate sections. Didn't realize. (Like I said, I'm really new at this.)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code and implement it in your code and also change color value in CSS which you want.

```css
#customers {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
#customers thead th{
  background-color: gray;
}
#customers tbody th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Alfreds Futterkiste</th>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Berglunds snabbköp</th>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Centro comercial Moctezuma</th>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Ernst Handel</th>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Island Trading</th>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Königlich Essen</th>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</th>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</th>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>North/South</th>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Paris spécialités</th>
    <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```